# How do I split text with strange characters?

Tags: php, regex, split, explode

I want to split part of this user-entered URL on the slashes (//). Everything I try just returns false or an empty string. How can I do it?

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
$url = urldecode('aaa%BAbbb//ccc%D0ddd');
echo 'url: ' . $url . "\n";
$test = mb_split('//', $url);
$test2 = explode("//", $url);
$test3 = mb_ereg("//", $url);

echo "test: " . json_encode($test) . "\n-----------\n";
echo "test2: " . json_encode($test2) . "\n------------\n";
echo "test3: " . json_encode($test3) . "\n------------\n";
```

https://3v4l.org/a252W

thanks

Comment: Because these byte sequences are not valid UTF-8 to begin with, `json_encode` returns false here - but that does not mean the rest did not work. Stop using json_encode as a debug tool(?), put `var_dump($url, $test, $test2, $test3);` at the end of your script instead, and … voila.

Comment: It seems the issue is `json_encode()`, because if you do `print_r($test)` it returns the proper array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`explode()` works and json_encode wasn't working to output the results. var_dump and print_r work to output the results.